# Glassfish deploy error "Archive type of MyProject.jar was not recognized"

Tags: java, rest, deployment, jar, glassfish

I've created a dynamic web application and i'd like to deploy it with glassfish. I've successed build my sources to MyProject.jar. But when i deployed it, the following error displayed:

> remote failure: Archive type of /home/davenlin/MyProject/build/MyProject.jar was not recognized

My project is just a normal Restful application, not ejb application, so i don't know if i must generate a MyProject.war instead of MyProject.jar.

Please help me. Thanks !

Comment: Rather clearly when you expand the short: java archive (jar) and web archive (war). So you are building a web application ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, because my comment was rather unexplanatory: 
Web applications are handled by application servers or servlet containers.
Both do quiet a lot of work for you and web applications are not comparable 
to
desktop or standalone java applications. 
While your standalone applications are deployed as jar - files and then executed by the JVM, 
web applications are
executed by the container (application server / servlet container).
So this does require your application to provide additional configuration 
and affords the archive itself to have a different structure. 
So even if you are just exposing some web services to build a restful 
application, your application server will do things for you such as
forwarding requests to the right classes, translate query and post 
parameters into java - objects accessable by your own classes respectivly 
your own objects and returning your response to the clients.
The interesting thing about it is:
The additional files in the web - archive are usually xml - files and web - 
related files such as html, css, js.
So this does not distinguish war's from jar's as you can also package 
additional resources within a jar. 
The basic but now obsolete requirement on a war - file is that it contains 
a deployment descriptor (which is again is an xml - file) 
to configure your application , its context and the relative url (more concrete : url - patterns) it uses
 , but as this requirement is obsolete someone may still think that this distinguishing is obsolete, too.